# Persist Users in Strongloop Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

What have you done to persist the User data in production? Is there an easy way to find the schema of the User model so it can be reproduced in a database?

(Preemptive Note: DiscoverSchema finds the schema of the database, not the model)

(Also, I know the docs say the User model can be persisted by setting the file property in the default db datasource, but I have security, scalability, and durability concerns with that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should persist users into your chosen database via a connector.

The file property is only used to persist data to the filesystem and is NOT recommended for production. For production, you should use one of the connectors (MongoDB, MySQL, etc) to persist your data.

See the docs to find out what properties are part of the built-in User model or change the default database settings to persist the User model to the filesystem to see what properties are available in the JSON file output. If you don't understand all this, go through the [tutorial series](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example) to get an understanding of all these concepts. Cheers. ;)

Comment: I don't think that info is in the documentation. If it is, I couldn't find it. Looking at the db file is a great solution that I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of. Thanks!

Comment: You're right about the info not being the docs. That said, you can find the properties in the LoopBack source code: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.json#L3

Answer (score 6):

1. setup a database.
2. define a new datasource by editing the ./server/datasources.json by adding your database, for example:

```js
"mongodb_dev": { 
    "name": "mongodb_dev",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "host": "127.0.0.1", 
    "database": "devDB", 
    "username": "devUser", 
    "password": "devPassword", 
    "port": 27017 
  }
```

2. Update your ./server/model-config.json to have the built in models use your new datasource :

```js
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb_dev"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb_dev",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb_dev",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb_dev",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb_dev",
    "public": false
  }
}
```

3.Create server/create-lb-tables.js file to move the built-in tables to your database with the following

```js
var server = require('./server');
var ds = server.dataSources.mongodb_dev;// <<<<<<note the datasource name
var lbTables = ['User', 'AccessToken', 'ACL', 'RoleMapping', 'Role'];
ds.automigrate(lbTables, function(er) {
  if (er) throw er;
  console.log('Loopback tables [' + lbTables + '] created in ', ds.adapter.name);
  ds.disconnect();
});
```

4. Run the script
   `cd server` 
   `node create-lb-tables.js`

This is a link to the official docs about putting built in models on your db

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+database+tables+for+built-in+models

Answer (score 0):

Since no one actually shared how to accomplish this, I built this example using the example-mysql repo from strongloop and tweaked 2 files.

- model-config.json (change the built-in models from `db` to your datasource)
- bin/automigrate.js (add additional automigrate functions for each model)

See how here: https://github.com/mikesparr/loopback-example-users-to-mysql

Good luck!

Comment: Would you like to submit a PR with your changes to the actual `loopback-example-mysql` repo as a separate step?

Comment: Not sure if necessary, but could fork and PR if people thought it worthwhile. I also learned that the first param in automigrate() can be an array of models `(['User','AccessToken','ACL','RoleModel','Role'], ...)` thanks to Raymond Feng, one of the main contributors. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a persistent(Mongo or any other) datasource using `slc loopback:dataSource`
2. Edit `model-config.json` and mention above created datasource.
3. Restart server